# Why does this MOSFET switch on so slowly?

Tags: mosfet, switches

I am learning Tina and drew this simple MOSFET switch:

[image: simple MOSFET switch]

Adjusting P1 will at a certain point switch on the MOSFET, which I expected to  saturate immediately. However when I look at the DC transfer characteristic, it turns on 'slowly' when the gate voltage moves between 3.5V and 4.7V

[image: DC transfer characteristic]

I confirm this by setting P1 to 4.3%, where the MOSFET seems to be half-conducting and thus dissipating 249W:

[image: voltages & currents]

How can this be? I thought that this kind of MOSFET was a switch but it seems to behave like a BJT (albeit in a narrow gate voltage range)?

EDIT: Thanks to for the answers, all +1, which thoroughly enlightened me; I accepted Andy's answer simply because it corresponded best to my lack of understanding.

Comment: Every transistor has a quasi-linear region

Comment: _"I thought that this kind of MOSFET was a switch"_ - There's your problem, that assumption is false. MOSFETs _behave_ as a switch if you drive them in an appropriate way, much like BJTs behave as a switch if you drive them appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However when I look at the DC transfer characteristic, it turns on
>   'slowly' when the gate voltage moves between 3.5V and 4.7V

I'm assuming here that you don't mean "slow" in time but that you mean it doesn't instantly turn fully-on as you reach some precise voltage threshold.

This is what a MOSFET does - if you wish to use it as a switch then you apply a suitable voltage level on the gate (relative to the source) in as quick a time as you can. Maybe 12 to 15 volts or, for logic level MOSFETs, only 5 volts is needed. Then it behaves like a switch.

If you wish to use the MOSFET as an amplifier then you apply a linear voltage to the gate to get a (somewhat) linear voltage at the output. Notice the voltage gain in your circuit - For a change in gate voltage of about 1.15 volts you get a change in output voltage of about 100 volts. That's a gain of about 87 if you want it in simple numbers.

If you looked at gate voltage from 4.3 volts to 4.5 volts, the output voltage changes about 25 volts - that's a gain of 125.

> it seems to behave like a BJT (albeit in a narrow gate voltage range)?

A biploar transistor might totally switch on with a base-emitter voltage change from 0.6 volts to 0.7 volts. As a range that is 0.1 volts with an offset of 0.65 volts and if you compared this to your mosfet switching on in a range of 3.5 to 4.65 volts (1.15 volts) it isn't that dissimilar.

0.1/0.65 = 15% and 1.15/4 is about 29% so relatively speaking a BJT and a MOSFET are similar.

Answer (score 5):

> I thought that this kind of MOSFET was a switch

Well, it is a transistor, just like a BJT. It might have been designed optimized for either being totally pinched off or fully on, but that doesn't mean it doesn't have a relative gate voltage range in between those two extremes.

> which I expected to saturate immediately.

A MOSFET's gate needs to be charged, i.e. it works like one half of a capacitor.

Now, with a charging current of 3.55 pA, that might take a while – with a datasheet saying it has a total gate charge of ca 67 nC, a little more than 5 hours to fully charge. (It doesn't work that way, because capacitor charge curves don't lead to constant current, but it's an initial estimate).

Answer (score 1):

All switches have terminals and the terminal is like a parallel capacitance during transition. This rises with small gaps used to make lower RdsOn and lower gate resistance. *MOSFETS may have smaller RdsOn than Rce of a BJT and larger T values than a BJT for some types in the same power switch category, but not all.*

This is why IGBT's use MOSFET inputs and BJT outputs for very high current high voltage are popular. Yet MOSFET and IGBT designs have gone thru at least 7 generations each reducing this T constant while increasing Vout max. Thus giving more flexible choices for IGBT's and MOSFET's vs cost. (These improvements are not free, yet diverse)

A Figure of Merit (FoM) is often used by designers to choose these desirable characteristics such as this T=RC constant. It is also used to design faster turn off and slower turn on to prevent commutation "shoot thru" when both N and P channel devices are ON at the same time, using a parallel diode and R values to drive the gate faster OFF.

These FoM parameters are design specs not in the datasheets but depend on Ciss, Q , Coss values and Rg, RdsOn values.

Since the Ciss is a nonlinear dependent on Vgs, designers must decide if their gate drive like a current source ( high Z) or a voltage source (low Z) to estimate the transition time.

When you activate a switch this T=time constant depends on chip size and structural geometry and lithographic size.

> In your case , you are adding Rpot to the internal Rg value and thus controlling the gate rise time with Ciss during the transition voltage region Vgs=Vth.

My rule of thumb for BGT cascaded switches is to choose an Rce that is 20x smaller or use Ic/Ib=10 to 20 which tends to be near 10% of the linear hFE.

Then for MOSFET's cascaded from high RdsON CMOS to low RdsOn power switches say from 50 mA to a 50A range load, is to consider the Rg/RdsOn ratio and take 10% of this. to determine current gain when charging Ciss at the optimal speed.
The result is RdsOn ratios from one stage to the next , I choose roughly 1% with a wide tolerance. for the reduction in RdsOn or  amplify this  switch ratio.

Thus optimal speed would never be a 74HCxx CMOS gate with ESR or RdsOn of 50 ohms and a power MOSFET with RdsOn with 50 mOhms (1000:1) so an intermediate driver is necessary.  In future remember these ratios when choosing a design to see how it affects speed.

Your mileage may vary.